# ElasticSearch has_child query min_children fraction, not count

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am looking for a way to issue an ElasticSearch [has_child query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-has-child-query.html#_min_max_children) where `min_children` can be specified as the fraction of all children that satisfy the child query. The `has_child` query API supports a `min_children` field, but this specifies a minimum count of child documents that need to match, not a fraction. Is there a way to do this, for example using scripting?